# d3.style won't set width of HTML element

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

This one is fairly simple, but very weird:

```
var dims = this.placeholder.node().getBoundingClientRect();

this.mapContainer = d3.select('body').append('div')
  .classed('map-container', true)
  .style({
    position : 'absolute',
    width : dims.width,
    height : dims.height,
    top : dims.top,
    left : dims.left
  });
```

`dims.width`, `dims.height`, etc. return non-zero values, but the div that I get is just plain `<div class="container" style="position:absolute;"></div>`

I can set other style values in the console (`d3.select('.map-container').style({color:'red','background-color':'blue'})` works fine), but setting width `d3.select('.map-container').style({width:30,top:40})` does nothing at all.

Here's a straight jsbin where it also doesn't work: http://jsbin.com/gequrasivo/1/edit?html,js,output

What's going on here?

Answer (score 2):

It's because CSS style values require a unit.

```
this.mapContainer = d3.select('body').append('div')
  .classed('map-container', true)
  .style({
    position : 'absolute',
    width : dims.width + 'px',
    height : dims.height + 'px',
    top : dims.top + 'px',
    left : dims.left + 'px'
  });
```

works fine.

Comment: You can also use `.attr()` instead of `.style()`.

Comment: I don't think you can with an HTML element (at least for things like top and left, which are only controlled via CSS in HTML).